# CURL not returns whole html source

Tags: php, curl

TI want grab remote site html code, for this I use CURL, this my code

```
    $URL = "http://example.com/";

    $ch = curl_init();


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');


    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

This works good almost for every sites, I obtain full HTML content.

But there is 1 website, which grabing result is html code to `</head>`, that is after ending `head` tag, curl not gets html source.

When I see this website html source via browser `view source`, here is whole html (site works also good).

What may be reason, that curl dont get whole html source?

Comment: curl does not selectively fetch anything, unless you tell it to (e.g. an http partial get). It will returns EXACTLY what was sent to it. If you only get partial content, then something on the sending side is changing its output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this site prevent others to crawl their content. I suggest you to add `User-Agent` in your request header to simulate web browser.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the website is redirecting you. Add this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

This will make curl follow redirection.

Comment: I trying this, not helps, result is again partial content